# How to iterate through self made dictionary and access its attributes in DJANGO templates.?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am getting a Dictionary from the ajax Base function
**{'Name': 'Dawn Bread Milky', 'Pricse': 60, 'Barcode': 11111, 'Quantity': 2, 'Total_pricse': 120}**
I send it to an template using

```
genrate_bill = {"Order_ID":Bill_Genrated.id,
                                'Khaata':is_Khaata,'CustomerName':is_Khaata.name,
                                'Bill': Bill_Genrated,
                                'CartList':cart[0], ## Here is an dict i send
                                'SubTotal':total_amount,
                                'Discount':0,
                                'TotalPricse':total_amount
                                }
```

Problem is that how can I access it KeyVallues Like in Django template

```
                           {% for item in CartList %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">Rs.{{item.Pricse}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{item.Quantity}}</td>
                                <td class="text-right">Rs.{{item.Total_pricse}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
```

**It not showing any result**

Comment: What is `CartList`? The dictionary?

Comment: cart =[{'Name': 'Dawn Bread Milky', 'Pricse': 60, 'Barcode': 11111, 'Quantity': 2, 'Total_pricse': 120}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CartList` is a *dictionary*, not a list of dictionaries, so you access the items from the dictionary with:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ CartList.Name }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">Rs.{{ CartList.Pricse }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ CartList.Quantity }}</td>
    <td class="text-right">Rs.{{ CartList.Total_pricse }}</td>
</tr>
```

That being said, since `CartList` is a dictionary, and not a list of dictionaries, it might be better to rename it to `cart` or something similar. Furthermore often the keys are written in `snake_case`, not `PerlCase`. There is also a typo for `Pricse`: it is `price`, not <s>`pricse`</s>.

Comment: Thank u so much! it's a small mistake I am doing in locgic genration.